How can I prevent sensitive URLs from being sent to datadog using resourceEventMapper?
I'm struggling to prevent sensitive URLs from being captured and sent to Datadog in my React Native application.
I'm using resourceEventMapper to sanitize URLs before they're sent, but sensitive data is still appearing in Datadog.
Here's my code:
const sanitizeURL = (url) => {
  return url
    .replace(/cpf=\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}-\d{2}/g, 'cpf=[CPF_REMOVED]')
    .replace(/email=[^&]+/g, 'email=[EMAIL_REMOVED]');
};

const resourceEventMapper = (event) => {
    // Sanitize nested URLs in resourceContext
    if (event.resourceContext) {
      if (event.resourceContext._url) {
        event.resourceContext._url = sanitizeURL(event.resourceContext._url);
      }
      if (event.resourceContext._datadog_xhr && event.resourceContext._datadog_xhr.url) {
        event.resourceContext._datadog_xhr.url = sanitizeURL(event.resourceContext._datadog_xhr.url);
      }
      if (event.resourceContext.responseURL) {
        event.resourceContext.responseURL = sanitizeURL(event.resourceContext.responseURL);
      }
    }
  return event;
};

const initializeDatadog = () => {
  const config = new DdSdkReactNativeConfiguration(
    ...config
  );

  config.resourceEventMapper = resourceEventMapper;

  DdSdkReactNative.initialize(config);
};

initializeDatadog();

I tried using resourceEventMapper to sanitize URLs and prevent sensitive data from being sent to Datadog. I expected that the URLs would be sanitized or filtered out before being sent, but sensitive data is still appearing in the Datadog logs.
How can I properly sanitize or filter these URLs?
